# Tokens to change a block's visibility

Tags: blocks

I am trying to make a block visible only to pages whose URL matches user/[current-user:uid]/downloads, but I don't get anywhere.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: cant' you use user/*/downloads instead of token?

Comment: @AnoopJoseph OP want it to limit the block for current user i think.

Comment: I used it but still it does not pop-up.

Comment: @AnoopJoseph, this can also be done by access control. For a start just want to allow this to be visible under the specific structure.

Comment: you can use php code, use global $user; for getting current user.

Comment: no if I could it would be really easy. I am using the interface for the blocks, where you can assign a block to a region(header,featured etc...) and make that block "viewable" or not to certain pages.

Comment: Are you looking for code to use to achieve the task you are describing, or a module?

Comment: Hey @kiamlaluno. I am just looking of what to insert(no coding) in the field to achieve the block placement. If a module is needed then yes. Initially I thought it should be quite straightforward without the need of a module.

Comment: Can you checkout this module ? https://www.drupal.org/project/token_conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly sure you can't do this from within the Blocks interface, but would be delighted learn otherwise.

A strategy to try would be to create a Views block that will display or not as required. A View over Users with a Contextual Filter that takes the Raw Value from URL, picking out a given path component, would be a start. You can then filter the view by User: Active.

If that all works out then your View will show. You can then get the content you want for your block by using a Rewrite of User: name field and, perhaps also, using Global: Text area in the header. (Well, you might be able to get the content this way. Depends on what's needed in the block.)

When you add the View block, you'll do something such as user/*/downloads, but the block will show depending on current user matching the contextual filter.